# Android: thread stop working

Tags: java, android

It reads image from the channel and write it to card. the image in card is completely written and is fine. The only problem is thread in hanged and does not execute any line after that loop.

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub'
      // Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    System.out.println("Inside doinback"+ RemoteScreen.out.toString());
        try {
            RemoteScreen.out.write(210);
            //Home.threadloop = false;  
             Bitmap bitmap = null;  
            String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            String fileName = "a.png";
            String imageInSD = baseDir + File.separator + fileName; 
                System.out.println(imageInSD);
            if (is!= null) {
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
                try {
                    // Log.i("IMSERVICE", "FILERECCC-1");
                    //ContextWrapper context = null;
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(imageInSD);   
                    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                    byte[] aByte = new byte[1024]; 
                    int bytesRead;  
                    //thread stuck in this loop and does not move forward 
                    while ( (bytesRead = is.read(aByte)) > 0  ) {
                        if (bytesRead == 1)
                            break; 
                        bos.write(aByte, 0, bytesRead);  
                   System.out.println("Loop"+aByte); 

                    }   

                   bos.close();

                Log.i("IMSERVICE", "out of loop");     
                    java.io.FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(imageInSD);
               bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD); 

            Log.i("IMSERVICE", "saved");
                if (bitmap != null) 
                    System.out.println(bitmap.toString());

                } catch (IOException ex) {    
                    // Do exception handling      
             //     Log.i("IMSERVICE", "exception ");
                }
            }
             publishProgress(b);   
             b = null; 
             ch = 4646;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



     return null;
}
```

log trace shows following error.

```
   05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
  05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
  05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
   05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
    05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
    05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
  05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
 05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
 05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):    at com.rms.remotedesktop1.screencahnge.doInBackground(screencahnge.java:43)
 05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):    at com.rms.remotedesktop1.screencahnge.doInBackground(screencahnge.java:1)
 05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 05-10 20:34:42.715: E/AndroidRuntime(1135):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

Comment: do you have the write permission? Post the whole stacktrace

Comment: check now this might clear

Comment: Could you clarify which is line 43 of screencahnge? That's where the crash is occuring.

Comment: RemoteScreen.out.write(210); is line 43

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the logcat, the code is crashing at line 43 with a Null Pointer Exception, and I can't tell which line 43 is. However:

- Have you checked that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` is returning non `null`? It maybe that there is no external storage directory, or you don't have permission to know about it.
- It is also worth reading the developer pages, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory(), which note that you shouldn't write to that directory, which you seem to be doing.

Comment: no it had problem in RemoteScreen.out.write(210) but i have resolved now having error 
problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by myself. There was error in static variable who was changing his value due to logical error in code.